# Typesetting text with math

Tags: formatting

```
 elecb=12      
 Text [Style["b win with" elecb "voces", Red, Bold]]
```

1) here elecb is placed before b win.

```
 Text [Style["b win with"<> elecb <> "voices", Red, Bold]]
```

2) here it is correctly placed but the <> are visible

3) I want only b to be bold

Comment: All red, only number is bold:  `Row[{Style["b win with ", Red], Style[elecb, Red, Bold], Style[" voces", Red]}]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`StringForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringForm.html) or [`StringTemplate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringTemplate.html).

```
x = 1/2;

Text@StringForm["The value of x is ``", x]
```

You can also do

```
Text@StringForm["The value of `` is ``", Style["x", Bold], x]
```

Personally I prefer formatting directly in the notebook. I select `x` in the string and press Ctrl-I for italic.  Bold is a bit more problematic because in input cells everything is bold.  So I press Ctrl-B once to make it not bold, then again to make it bold.   I get the following, which looks much better in the notebook (paste it):

```
Text@StringForm["The value of \!\(\*StyleBox[\"x\",\nFontWeight->\"Bold\"]\) is ``", x]
```

For this particular string, I would press Ctrl-Shift-T after selecting `x` to make it TraditionalForm instead of bold, which give me this:

```
Text@StringForm["The value of \!\(\*FormBox[\(x\),TraditionalForm]\) is ``", x]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in the Front End by creating a text cell and then entering an inline cell; see [Mixing Text and Formulas](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/MixingTextAndFormulas.html).

Create a new text cell (Format > Style > Text) and enter your desired text

> [image]

Replace the "X" with an inline cell: [Insert > Typesetting > Start Inline Cell](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/menuitem/Typesetting.html)

> [image]

Assuming you have already evaluated the expression `elecb`

```
elecb=10;
```

You enter a [`Dynamic`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dynamic.html) expression in the newly created inline cell

> [image]

You then select [Evaluation > Evaluate in Place](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/menuitem/EvaluateInPlace.html)

> [image]

Finally, you use the Front End menu items to format the rest of the text as you wish

> [image]

Note that the 10 reflects the `Dynamic` value of `elecb` and will update when `elecb` is assigned new values.